# Performance Counter Logs - Migrating lots of them from Win 2000 to Win 2003

Tags: performance, migration, windows-server-2000, perfmon

I have a bunch of performance counter logs setup on a Windows 2000 machine that I would like to move lock, stock and barrel to a Win 2003 machine on the same network.

I can't see a way to export that details of all the perf logs and import them, so any ideas on where to look under `C:\WINNT` for the raw perf log configurations would be good, or any other suggestions at all would be welcome.

If it cannot be done, that info in that regard would also be very welcome :)

Thanks!

Ciaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this in my experience. Had to move them all manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command line utility logman.exe that ships with windows.  Logman allows you to create/import/export  perf counters traces.
It is a little effort to create the data collector, but once you export it to XML file you can import it on any other machine.

Hope this works.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a good plan but I have run into a problem. On the machine where the current log files reside, there is no native logman.exe. The machine is running Win 2000 (5.00.2195) Service Pack 4. 
I tried to copy logman from a Windows 2003 machine but when I run 'logman /?' I get an error dialog box with a message: 'The procedure entry point PdhPlaGetLogFileNameW could not be located in the dymnamic link library psh.dll'. Any other ideas on how I can get logman.exe to work on this Win 2000 machine?

Comment: You will need the pdh.dll file as well in order for logman to work 
check out this 
http://www.petri.co.il/forums/archive/index.php/t-13978.html

Comment: Thanks for those links - however, when I run 'logman /?' there is no verb to export. When I checked the version of logman that ships with Win 2008 I see that there is, but if I try to run that version under Win 2000 I get an error saying 'logman is not a valid Win 32 application'. I looks like I'll have to do this manually, but thanks for all the help!